# How to store images and videos in mongoDB along with other form data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, file-upload

I'm new to mongoDB,

I want to fill a form for a post model and one of the fields is file-type (image or video), can I store the attached media in the same mongo document ? If not, how should I go about doing this and is there a helpful guide I can follow ?

[this is how my backend looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw4sa.png)

[this is my Post model that I'm going to fill it in the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLHAC.png)

NB : I'm using angular in my front-end

Comment: You should use object storage service or cdn service for that type of media content storage.

Check --> Google Object Storage, Amazon Cloud Front CDN

Answer (score 0):

If the media is relatively small like an 8K thumbnail then you can store it as a binary type field as a peer to the rest of your ints, strings, and dates.

However, an individual document cannot be larger than 16MB so such an approach in general is not feasible especially for video content.

You can use the `gridFs` utils which are bundled with the client side drivers.  A comprehensive example is posted here:  [How to save images from url into mongodb using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70541999/how-to-save-images-from-url-into-mongodb-using-python?noredirect=1#comment124714908_70541999)

If you do not require the media to be managed by the database storage subsystem, a practical alternative is to store the media in an AWS S3 bucket (or Azure or GCP equivalent) and store just the path to the content in mongodb.